# When deploy with hardhat, if there is the same contract name, how should I put the argument in getContractFactory?

Tags: hardhat

I am currently trying to use OpenZeppelin's upgrade plugin. I am changing a logic contract, but it has the same name as the previous contract.

this is deploy UUTP code

```
import { ethers, upgrades } from "hardhat";

async function main() {
    const _ERC721 = await ethers.getContractFactory("ERC721");
    console.log("Deploying Box...");
    const ERC721 = await upgrades.deployProxy(_ERC721,{kind:'uups'})
    await ERC721.deployed();
    console.log("Box deployed to:", ERC721.address);
}
```

this is upgrade logic contract code

```
async function main() {
    // Here ERC721 is the name of the contract being updated.
    const _ERC721 = await ethers.getContractFactory("ERC721"); 
    console.log("Upgrading Box...");
    await upgrades.upgradeProxy(PROXY, _ERC721);
    console.log("_MyERC721V2 upgraded");
}
```

Looking at the getContractFactory() parameters in both codes, the contracts have the same name "ERC721". But Solidity files are different. How should I tell them apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the same argument in both `getContractFactory()`, but it doesn't allow for easy reproduction of the upgrade process. I would recommend using different versioned contract names such as `ERC721V2`.

See: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/can-the-same-implementation-contract-name-be-used-with-upgradeproxy/4071/2

Comment: Hmmm... Any ideas like using getContractFactoryFromArtifact() or passing the url as a parameter?

Comment: I haven't seen  any uses of deployProxy or upgradeProxy with getContractFactoryFromArtifact() and getContractFactory() only takes the name of the contract as the parameter. Is there a reason you need to use the same implementation contract name with upgradeproxy?

Comment: no.... That was an example. However, since this part is a frequent concern during development, I asked if there were any good ideas... Thank you for your kind reply !!